# Find a keystore file containing a particular SHA-1

Tags: files, find

I have the SHA-1 of a file. I have a keystore file which contains this SHA-1. But I don't know where this keystore file is on my system. Is there any way to find the keystore file that contains the SHA1?

In more details, I am on the hunt for a `.keystore` file that I used to submit an Android app a while back and don't remember the name of the file. I was able to find a SHA-1 hash in the `.apk` that should match a hash that the keystore contains. I don't have any ideas as to where the keystore is saved, so I guess you could say I am blindly looking.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this fully, you have an SHA1 hash, and are looking for a file that matches the hash? Or a file that contains (a representation of) the hash? What do you mean with a "keystore file"? Do you have some known (set of) file(s) that might contain the hashes of other files, or do you need to go blindly looking?

Comment: Sorry for my poor description. I am on the hunt for a .keystore file that I used to submit an Android app a while back and don't remember the name of the file. I was able to find a SHA1 hash in the .apk that should match a hash keystore contains. I don't have any ideas as to where the kestore is saved, so I guess you could say I am blindly looking.

Comment: @don_crissti The keystore file wouldn't contain the SHA-1 as easily searchable text (it's in binary, and this warrants explanation), so generic grep answers don't answer this question. Furthermore limiting the search to files that look like keystores will drastically improve performance.

Comment: @Gilles - I didn't know it's a binary file, thanks for the explanation. Vote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
$ cat test-keystore.sh
#!/bin/bash
keytool -list -keystore "$1" -protected 2>&1 | grep 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 >/dev/null
$ find -name '*.keystore' -exec ~/test-keystore.sh '{}' \; -print
/home/tavianator/android-prod.keystore
```

Replace 00:00... with your actual hash of course :)